# Why can a volatile type be constant when returned by a constant functions?

Tags: c++, function, constants, volatile

A c++ class has a member functions with the following code:

```
const volatile stats_t& get_stats() const{
        return stats;
    }
```

What can be the reason to use both const and volatile together? What is this function exactly achieving ? If the return type is const, does not it contradict its purpose with the use of volatile?

Comment: In C++ `const` means `read-only`, not that it will never change. So the variable can be changed by external factors, but not by your program.

Answer (score 9):

`const` is not the contrary of `volatile`

Marking something as `const` means "this won't be modified by this piece of code, it's a constant value/pointer/whatever"

Marking something as `volatile` means "don't cache this value, it might suddenly be changed by an external IO operation, interrupt or something"

They serve different purposes. const is more of a "*code don't-modify rule*" while volatile a "*cache, reordering and compiler optimization rule*"

Answer (score 2):

A possible scenario is that you have a main thread, that READS the stats, and a secondary thread that updates the stats. As such, the main thread would want to "get" the stats to know where they are stored. This would be `const` because we don't want the main thread to modify the stats, but also `volatile`, because the stats are being updated regularly by the secondary thread [where, of course, the value is not const].

The `const` after the function just means `this` is a `const` pointer in the function (in other words, we will not change the contents of the object in the call to that particular function).

Of course, the same scenario applies if `stats_t` is actually a pointer to some interesting registers in a piece of hardware, that gets updated by the hardware. The compiler can't know when/how they are updated, so must not "assume it never changes unless a function is called".

Edit: Note however, that `volatile` does in NO WAY guarantee threads and operations correctness in a multithreaded environment. It ONLY means that the compiler will not optimise away accesses to a variable because it already has read the value at some earlier point. To guarantee thread behaviour, you really need atomic operations or locks [this is a subject that is fairly complex, and I could probably write several pages on the subject, and an expert may well end up writing a whole book]

Comment: `volatile` is not a solution in threading, `std::atomic` is better. `volatile` is really for hardware.

Comment: Well, possibly. Depends on exactly that the content is, how you are dealing with it, etc. But I will add something to the effect of what you are saying.